# MySQL query records from 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with 2 columns. Each column is populated with numbers.
I need to return all records that matches the following criteria:

It will check the first character from column1. If it equals 1 then it will check the last character from column2. If it equals 7 then it will count the total length of column1 + column2. If it equals 12 then it will return this results.

Pseudo code (Vba)

```
For k = 1 To 100
col1 = Cells(k, 1).Value
For v = 1 To 100
col2 = Cells(v, 2).Value
If Left(col1, 1) = "1" Then
If Right(col2, 1) = "7" Then
If Len(col1) + Len(col2) = 12 Then
MsgBox col1 & "-" & col2
End If
End If
End If
Next
Next
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest actually trying to learn SQL. A [select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement and some [string-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) will acheive this easily. Experiment online with a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) and you don't even need to install mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function names in mysql are almost identical: `left()`, `right()`, `char_length()`. You need to combine them in the `where` clause with `and` operator because you want to return records that satisfy all criteria.

```
select * from yourtable
where Left(col1, 1) = '1' and Right(col2, 1) = '7' and char_length(col1) + char_length(col2) = 12
```